# A warning that 'getAt' cannot be applied to 'Integer' in Groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

In this line of my Groovy code:

```
def document = someQuery().Document[0]
```

Method someQuery will return a Json Array and this worked well. Since editor doesn't know property, it underlined `Document`, and shows a warning at `[0]`, says:

```
'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'
```

So what is the better way to do this to avoid this warning?

Comment: Try to get whole object with `def document = someQuery().Document`.

Comment: Do you have any types in your Groovy?  What does `someQuery` return?  Have you set it to return a `Map`?

Comment: I agree with tim_yates. I have started to define types in method signatures that I use from outside a class, because I periodically ran into problems using dynamic typing there,.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly for `.getAt(0)` and `.getAt(-1)`, you can also use `.first()` and `.last()`, respectively, and Intellij will stop complaining.

Source: I just tried it. (See getAt doesn't expect an Integer here: [code-completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDNbD.png))

```
    def shortId(def longId){
        longId?.toString()?.split('[/:]')?.last()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have code that looks like:

```
def sql = //... (new/existing connection to the database)
sql.eachRow { row ->
    //Do something...
}
```

Replace this with:

```
def sql = //... (new/existing connection to the database)
sql.eachRow { GroovyResultSet row ->
    //Do something...
}
```

This will force your editor to look at methods from GroovyResultSet rather than methods with the same name attached to objects during groovy compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic methods and properties to intellij so it knows about them.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Dynamic+Methods+and+Properties

You can also use [groovydsl](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) to let intellij know how your code should work.